# Border around menu button

Tags: css

I want the same effect than this post : https://generatepress.com/forums/topic/border-around-a-single-menu-button/ and I’m halfway there but can’t get the top border to be lower.

The page I need help with: https://duplicate.naftali-estate.co.za/

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add this CSS in your file. Remove all the CSS that you have added for "pricelist" class.

```
.pricelist a span{
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 12px;
}
.pricelist a span.plus{
   border:0;
   padding:0;
}
.pricelist a span .underline_dash{
    display:none;
}
```

This CSS will make the nav as seen in the screenshot.

[image]